# MagicUV not pasting correctly

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Started using the magic uv addon, and it was functioning great for about a day. Now it's suddenly not copy and pasting faces correctly. Or in other words, I select the faces that I want to copy, copy them, then select the faces I want to paste the UVs at (which are exactly the same), paste the uvs, and the result is skewed. Here's a picture to better illustrate what I mean:

[image]

Does anyone know what would suddenly cause magic uv to behave in this manner? I've tried completely resetting the layout settings to factory, and opting out of magic uv, saving and quitting, then restarting and turning back on magic uv. None of that worked. For some reason, MagicUV is just suddenly very broken.

Also, it's not just these faces. Any face I copy and paste is broken now.

Comment: I think I just found a lead on why this is happening. I noticed that UV data for the face on the right can be moved as a single island, but the one on the left must be selected in parts. I don't know why this is happening, and merging the vertices, etc, doesn't seem to be resulting in a single selectable uv island....trying to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the face you pasted the UV to has a different vertex order than the original. You can fix that rotating the face UV:

Select the face and go to: **Face** -> **Face Data** -> **Rotate UVs**

You may or may not need to rotate two times.

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Comment: That's what I figured out as well, however this is not convenient for me, and it's still quicker to just unwrap projected from view. Was a good addon up until that point.